# How can I get the inspect element HTML Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to get a HTML that is not the page_source, I need the one that is generated when you open the page.
I have seen and tried all the solutions I could find but nothing really works.

I do not need any code since I do not know how to do it. I have tried with page_source but I need the inspect element HTML.

Could someone explain a good example with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return html code of dynamic page using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891621/return-html-code-of-dynamic-page-using-selenium)

Comment: Not at all, it doesn't fit it with my problem, isn't there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

From [Get current HTML of rendered page using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954847/get-current-html-of-rendered-page-using-selenium]) I suggest you using

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html").get_attribute('outerHTML')
```